# Using a range slider to continuously change an input value even when the mouse is still holding onto the slide

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use my range slider to change the value or 'price' of another element's ID. The range slider is based on page views. I got the range slider to do that, but only after a drag and let go. I am hoping to get it to dynamically change, so the price changes even before I let go of the mouse. Here is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
          <div id="slide-container">
            <input
                type="range"
                min="5"
                max="200"
                step="5"
                value="100"
                class="slider"
                id="myRange"
            />
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 const slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
 function updateSlider() {
     pageViews = document.getElementById("views");
     pageViews.innerHTML = slider.value;
     updatePrice();
 }

 slider.addEventListener("change", updateSlider);
```

Is there a better way to do this so the function updatePrice runs even when I have the mouse clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`oninput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) seems to be exactly what you need.

Quick example:

```js
document.querySelector('input')
    .addEventListener('input', evt => {
  console.log(evt.target.value)
});
```

```html
<input type="range">
```